# Results summary @total not showing in Drupal Views Full Search after search

Tags: search, drupal, view, drupal-views

I've got a search page here:
http://freerange.raisingofamerica.org/resources

It shows the results summary when the page first loads:
"Found 44 resources related to your search. Use filters above to narrow results."

When I search for something, the total results summary disappears. It just says, "Use filters above to narrow results." I want it to show me how many results I got from the search.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It must be some form alter issues. Can you show us the code where you have displayed the count variable

Comment: Here is another url to look at on the site - http://freerange.raisingofamerica.org/search?search_api_views_fulltext=America the search actually works fine. There is some setting on that view which is causing the issue to happen. Easiest way to debug it is in the view preview itself to check on the output.